# Problems with converting a JSON into a string array

Tags: java

I want to convert a JSON file into a string.

I want the loadFromJSON() method to take all of the following from the JSON file and remove them:

1. curly braces
2. quotes
3. colons
4. commas
5. brackets.

Then the method will split the String into a String array without any whitespace.

I expect the returned string to be:

`worldOne0000011111222225355worldTwo0000011111222225355`

which then could be split up into bits, like the following:

`String worldName = "worldOne";`,

`int[] data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};`,

`int worldWidth = 5;`,

`int worldHeight = 3;`,

`int xSpawn = 5;`,

`int ySpawn = 5;`

**My Current JSON File:**

```
{
  "gameWorlds": [
    {
      "worldName": "worldOne",
      "data": [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2
      ],
      "worldWidth": 5,
      "worldHeight": 3,
      "xSpawn": 5,
      "ySpawn": 5
    },
    {
      "worldName": "worldOne",
      "data": [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2
      ],
      "worldWidth": 5,
      "worldHeight": 3,
      "xSpawn": 5,
      "ySpawn": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about that?

Below is my attempt at the problem which currently doesn't work and needs fixing.

**Converting a JSON File into a String[]:**

```
public void loadFromJSON(String fileName) {
    String tempFile = TinyFile.loadFile("file.json");
    String jsonFile =  tempFile.replaceAll("\\}", " ") + tempFile.replaceAll("\\{", " ") + tempFile.replaceAll("\"", " ") +
            tempFile.replaceAll(",", " ") + tempFile.replaceAll("\\]", " ") + tempFile.replaceAll("\\[", " ") + tempFile.replaceAll(":", " ");
    String[] tokens = jsonFile.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        TinyDebug.debug("tokens", tokens[i]);
    }
}
```

**LoadFile() inside TinyFile.java:**

```
public static String loadFile(String filePath) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

        String line;
        while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        e.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Util.printErrorMessage("File Not Found");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

If you have a better solution, such as a way to read from a JSON file, please post that below.

Comment: Use Jackson and map directly to a POJO...

Comment: `String key = (String) jsonObject.get("name");` I don't see the "name" key in the posted json. By the way, Jackson is the JSON parser. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonparser.html

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu Sorry, I changed the name in the creation of this question. The post should reflect that now.

Comment: Check the json, it is not in valid format.

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu I updated the JSON doc.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" precisely. What is the output you expect, and what is the output you get? Why do you think you need to concatenate all the strings abtained after replacing quotes, colons, curly braces, etc? And more importantly, what are you trying to achieve? What's the point in transforming a structured JSON file into a meaningless sequence of words and numbers?

Comment: @JBNizet I expect the returned string to be: worldOne0000011111222225355worldTwo0000011111222225355 
which then could be split up into bits, like the following: 
`String worldName = "worldOne";`,
`int[] data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};`,
`int worldWidth = 5;`,
`int worldHeight = 3;`,
`int xSpawn = 5;`,
`int ySpawn = 5;`
 etc...

Comment: That's exactly why a structured standard format such as JSON is used: so that you don't have to write a complex parser to extract the information you need. Use a JSON parser, there are dozens of them. It will parse the JSON and give you back a Map, or even a POJO which matches with the JSON structure.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah exactly, I know, but I was having problems with the JSON parser and decided to just do this. Obviously, I haven't done enough research on this. I'll continue to read up on this problem. Sorry if my question was lacking in certain respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to write the JSO Class and parse it using Jackson parser.

You can parse the Json in many ways. Here we used json-simple to parser the json

1. if you find `{` then you should create JSONObject
2. if you find `[`, then create JSONArray

   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

   ```
   String ss = "{\"gameWorlds\":[{\"worldName\":\"worldOne\",\"data\":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],\"worldWidth\":5,\"worldHeight\":3,\"xSpawn\":5,\"ySpawn\":5}]}";
   Object obj;
   try {

       obj = parser.parse(ss);
       JSONObject base = (JSONObject) obj;
       JSONArray arrayGameWorld = (JSONArray) base.get("gameWorlds");
       for (int index = 0; index < arrayGameWorld.size(); index++) {
           JSONObject worldHeight = (JSONObject) arrayGameWorld.get(index);
           Long value = (Long) worldHeight.get("worldHeight");
           System.out.println(value);
           JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray) worldHeight.get("data");
           System.out.println(obj);
       }
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{ 'login' : 'user1', 'pass' : 'test' }";

User user = mapper.readValue(new File("~/user.json"), User.class);
```

And then override method `toString()` for your `User` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "login=" + this.login + ", pass=" + this.pass;
}
```